# Infinitesimal Transformation

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I came across this statement in the book "Quantum Field theory and the Standard Model" by Schwartz.

"We would now like to find all the representations of the Lorentz group. The Lorentz group itself is a mathematical object independent of any particular representation. To extract the group away from its representations, it is easiest to look at infinitesimal transformations."

I didn't understand how the concept of representation is related to infinitesimal transformation? How are these two concepts related?

Comment: Googled "lorentz group infinitesimal" and got the following:

http://www.physics.indiana.edu/~dermisek/QFT_08/qft-I-14-4p.pdf

Comment: "Infinitesimal transformations" means "Lie algebra". So, he says that it is easier to analyze representations of the Lie algebra of a group.